# How to access Azure Storage Account Container as Azure subscription service administrator

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-blob-storage

I am setting up azure blob storage setup but having trouble accessing a container via the Azure AD User Account Authentication Method. I am the subscription service administrator but are seeing this error(image below) when I try to view the container.

Authentication Error
[image]

I have tried to give myself the role Storage Blob Data Owner on the storage account in question, but this did not change the outcome.

Comment: `I have tried to give myself the role Storage Blob Data Owner on the storage account in question, but this did not change the outcome` - This should work. Please wait for some time. May be sign out and sign in again?

Comment: Yes. Please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory especially "Azure built-in roles for blobs" section (3rd paragraph).

Comment: I found this article helpful as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal
"When you create an Azure Storage account, you are not automatically assigned permissions to access data via Azure AD. You must explicitly assign yourself an Azure role for Azure Storage. You can assign it at the level of your subscription, resource group, storage account, or container."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment i got the same error like below.***

[image]

To resolve this issue, try to assign roles like below.

[image]

Make sure to `Enabled from all network`:

***In your storage account -> under security+ networking click networking -> Enabled from all networks and save***

[image]

Now, I am able to successfully upload the blob in the container like below.

[image]